# Apís docusign demo a producción

Tags: python, jwt

Buenas noches compañeros. Estoy usando las apis de docusign para una aplicacion en python, de momento tengo mi aplicacion jalando en DEMO o sandbox, la aplicacion ya la tengo lista para moverla a productivo. Leyendo un poco la documentación y los pasos que menciona ya la tengo en producción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle en produccion me lanza este mensaje y la verdad no se muy bien por que, ya que la cuenta si tiene cuenta de desarrollador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al bajar la  colleccion de postman prodcutiva, no logro por ninguna manera generar el accestoken y por ende que funcionen ninguna de las apis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que en sandbox no tengo problema alguno,logro generar el acces-token y que todo funcione sin problema. Tengo la ipotesis  de que no tengo en plan correcto contratado, en esta cuenta de docusign tengo este plan:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que este es el plan que nesecito para produccion Docusign:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo muestro un poco mi entorno de pruebas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que son muchas capturas pero es para intentar dar una buena explicación. Alguien que haya utilizado estas apis? que ya haya desplegado un proyecto en productivo?, Los planes estan algo caros y no quiero hacer un gasto inesecario.